# How to set different color for same text in D3?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am using D3 to have some text on lines. For some reason, I need some part of the text to have different color, For example, I might have black text then red text like this: "black(red)".
What is the best way to do this?
Can I have different color in a single text?
If I have to draw another text for the second color, how can I append it to first text element?

This is my how I generate texts:

```
       var texts = lines.append("svg:text")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.label;
        })
        .attr("class", "link-label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to deal with `<defs>` and gradients, you cannot set two or more `fill` attributes to the same `<text>`.

The easiest solution is breaking that text of yours and appending a [`<tspan>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan) with another style. *How* to break the text is a problem that depends on your exact goal, which you didn't specify in the question. In the following demo, I'm using a hyphen to break the texts.

Here it is:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = ["This is some text - with different colours",
  "This is another text - with different colours",
  "This is the last text - and the colours are still different"
];

var text = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 40 + i * 40
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.split("-")[0]
  })
  .append("tspan")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.split("-")[1]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400"></svg>
```

Comment: @daniel No worries. I'm seeing that you never accepted an answer you received at S.O. I suggest you rethink this, accepting is a polite way to acknowledge an working answer.